# Надо ли перенастраивать swap-раздел?

Tags: linux, диск, раздел, swap

Есть Linux Mint. На другом *физическом* диске был настроен раздел под swap.

На физическом диске со свопом были изменены разделы. В том числе в нескольких местах появились незанятые области размером около мегабайта. Но сам раздел свопа не перемещался и его размиер не менялся. Диск разбит в **MBR**, не GPT.

Надо ли что-то делать перед тем, как пользоваться линуксом? Надо ли настраивать swap?

Разбиение диска до изменения разделов:

[image: Разбиение диска до изменения разделов]

и после:

[image: Разбиение диска до изменения разделов]

Swap-раздел - это Other на 7.45 GB.

Содержимое файла `/etc/fstab`:

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sdb2 during installation
UUID=965d0cac-637e-46d3-881e-132caebadb95 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# swap was on /dev/sda6 during installation
UUID=71d38886-e09b-4a46-b3c0-02911b34296c none            swap    sw              0       0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я считаю что не надо.
Современные дистры linux используют UID для определения разделов и проблем быть не должно, если раздел не пересоздавался
После запуска linux просто проверьте что swap подключился

```sh
dmesg | grep -i swap
```

Если в вывод будет пустым, то

- узнайте имя правильного раздела(`sudo fdisk -l`)
- измените в `/etc/fstab` строку, соответствующую swap
- дайте команду `sudo mount -a`
- проверьте что swap подключился

Comment: Эм.. Диск в MBR, не в GPT. Так что использование UID вызывает сомнения. _"После запуска"_ - а что случится при запуске, если он всё же раздел не угадает? Он мне что-нибудь на другом разделе не испортит? И запуститься нормально сможет?

Comment: Тогда загрузитесь с Live CD/Flash и проверьте /etc/fstab

Comment: Дополнил вопрос. Действительно uuid. Значит всё будет нормально и ничего делать не надо?

Comment: Думаю что проблем не будет, но для подстраховки с live проверьте соответствие UUID вашему разделу. Посмотреть список можно, например, так `ls -l /dev/disk/by-uuid/`

Comment: @Qwertiy, в MBR такое тоже имеется

Comment: @Ancient, да, всё верно. У меня уже давно всё получилось. Точнее, получилось проверить, что ничего делать не надо :)